# Is $\{x_n\}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers. For any two sub-sequences $\{u_n\}$ and $\{v_n\}$ (with no repeated terms) of $\{x_n\}$, $|u_n-v_n|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then can we conclude that $\{x_n\}$ is convergent?

My approach:

Since $|u_n-v_n|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, I take $u_n=x_{n+1} $ for $n=1,2,3,4....$ and $v_n=x_n$ for $n=1,2,3,4....$. Now corresponding to preassigned $\epsilon\gt0$ there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|u_n-v_n|<\epsilon$ for $n\geq m $, i.e. $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\lt \epsilon$ for all $n\geq m$, Hence it can be shown that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Hence ${x_n}$ is convergent.

Am I correct?

Comment: This does not work since $x_{n+1}-x_n\to0$ does not imply tat $(x_n)$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough for $u_n - v_n \to 0$ for some particular pair of subsequences $u_n, v_n$.  The assumption is that it's true for **all** pairs of subsequences.

Hint: try a proof by contradiction.  If $x_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence, find subsequences $u_n$, $v_n$ such that $u_n - v_n$ does not go to $0$.

Comment: Your hint is an effective one.Thank you sir. :-)

Comment: sir, two cases arise in this problem when i tried to prove by contradiction. 1st one is, if $\{x_n\}$ has more than one limit points. 2nd one is, if $\{x_n\}$ has no limit points. For case-1, taking two sub-sequences converging to two different limit points we can get that $u_n-v_n$  does not go to zero. Now what will be my approach for case-2?

Comment: If $x_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence, take $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $N$, there are $j, k > N$ with $|x_j - x_k| \ge \epsilon$.  Let $u_n$ and $v_n$ be some suitable $x_j$ and $x_k$ ...

Comment: Hmm... That will be easier..

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not correct. Consider the sequence $$x_i={1\over 1}+{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+...+{1\over i}=\sum_{j=1}^i{1\over j}.$$

Then

- $\vert x_i-x_{i+1}\vert={1\over i+1}$ goes to zero, but
- the sequence $\{x_i\}$ diverges.

Comment: hmm.. that is correct...

Answer (score 1):

Take the sequence of partial sums of the series $\sum 1/n$, which will contradict your result.

Comment: hmm.. that is correct...